# Given the Latitude, Longitude and Altitude of Origin and Destination points, Calculate Distance & Bearing (from origin to destination)

Tags: trigonometry, physics, spherical-trigonometry

Realize that this is similar to many of the questions here.  However, I have not been able to find the answer that incorporates the altitude differences.

Given the Latitude, Longitude and Altitude of Origin and Destination points, I am looking for Distance & Bearing (from origin to destination).

Please assume:

| Point | Latitude | Longitude | Ground Elevation | Height Over Ground | Altitude Above Sea Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Origin | 41.099218 | -73.419432 | 23 | 200 | 223 |
| Destination | 41.158622 | -73.277665 | 40 | 0 | 40 |
| Difference | 0.059404 | 0.141767 | 17 | NA | -183 |

Using =ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-C2))*COS(RADIANS(90-C3))+SIN(RADIANS(90-C2))*SIN(RADIANS(90-C3))*COS(RADIANS(D2-D3))) in excel I have calculated the distance between these two points.  (assume column 1, row 1 = A1 ("Point"))

**Current ***Close But Not Exact*** Output:**

- Unknown Haversine Unit: 0.00213
- Miles: 8.44
- Kilometers: 13.59
- Meters: 13,587.43

This does not take into account the altitude differences.  Which could be dramatic.

**I AM SEEKING:**

- Math to incorporate the altitude differences.
- Math to determine Bearing from Origin to Destination

I have been working on this for a few days and would appreciate any guidance.  THANK YOU.

Comment: How do you think the altitude difference should be accounted for, in general? In this case there appears to be a possibility that you have line of sight between the locations, but if you take points whose latitudes and longitudes are farther apart it might not be possible to have line of sight due to the curvature of the Earth. Plotting only the path at sea level we have a circle; including altitude, we have some kind of spiral. Does the path need to account for mountains in the way?

Comment: How is the path between the two points defined? Should we consider whether the path is obstructed by the curved ground in between, or whether the two points are directly visible as they are high enough? And even considering the effects of gravity and refraction?

Comment: I assume that the altitude difference on different spot on a sphere will affect the distance.

Comment: There is no expectation of line of site.  Distance between 1 -  100 miles.  Before or over the horizon).

Comment: Path is not important.  Currently just interested in (as-the-crow-flies) distance between the two points.  That being said, it is the path of a munitition (baseball).  And while there could be a wall / object / mountain in the way, we are going to currently assume that is not a factor.  Might be a nice enhancement later.